# Google Contacts auto filled name but missing from api

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-contacts-api

I am implementing an api to pull contacts using Google Contacts Api. However, the result is different from what I have on Web version of Google Contacts. I can see name is auto filled when I add a contact by email. However, the name is missing when I pull data from api. Is there a way to get the name like Web version does?

Comment: Are you talking about doing something like this: http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/autocomplete-email-addresses-in-apps.html ?

Comment: @pointNclick No, but this looks great. I am asking about first and last name that was auto populated by Google contacts but missing from Google Contacts Api.

Comment: Have you tried checking in the OAuth2.0  Playground: https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ?

Comment: I don't know whether you're talking about retrieving contact data from within your domain or outside but I am pretty sure that without the user's consent, you wouldn't be able to retrieve the first name and last name of anyone outside your domain (whose contact info doesn't already exist) with only their e-mail ID due to privacy issues. The web version pulls a name if the user replies back and has enabled the option of sharing their details with people they respond to. So for retrieving such information, you might have to look into OAuth and request that information using the correct scopes.

Comment: @pointNclick When you create a contact on google.com/contacts and just type an email, the name will auto populate. I don't think I have exchange emails with this new contact before.

Comment: @angelokh: After looking into this for a while, I believe this might be one of the services which is not offered to the public.